# How to update a MongoDB table column for a particular id

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

Update a user table column in MongoDB:

```
User.update({'_id':'123456'},{$set: {verification_code:'null'}})
```

when i pass like

```
User.update(verification_code:'null'})
```

this its working for one user. if i have more users on database it is not updating

When I use like this it showing this error:

```
 User.update({'_id':'123456'},{$set: {verification_code:'null'}})
```

> /home/dileep/Documents/hng_04-03-2014/healthnextgen/app/controllers/verifications_controller.rb:16: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting => User.update({_id:user_id},{$set: {verification_code:'null'}}) ^ /home/dileep/Documents/hng_04-03-2014/healthnextgen/app/controllers/verifications_controller.rb:16: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end User.update({_id:user_id},{$set: {verification_code:'null'}}) ^

Comment: Your Schema (which is not listed in your question) probably does not allow the "String" you are passing in as 'null'.

Comment: And quote the $set like so `"$set"`

Comment: sorry if i change also its showing same error

Comment: when i pass like User.update(verification_code:'null'}) this its working for one user. if i have more users on database it is not updating

Comment: @DileepKumar Pass it like this means?

Comment: You need to set multi option to true to update multiple documents, db.collection.update(query, update, {multi : true})

Comment: i am not doing multiple documents at that time. I want to update column with that particular id of that document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoid perhaps?:

```ruby
User.where(_id: "123456").update(verification_code: "null")
```

Or the moped way:

```ruby
collections[:user].find(
    { _id: "123456" }
).update({ "$set" => { verification_code: "null" }})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
User.update(
    {_id:"123456"},
    {
       $set: 
            {verification_code:"null"}
    },
    {multi:true}
)
```

For more [info](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/).

Comment: I need to use this at rails controller . Here i want to pass that id like user_id like {_id:user_id}. user_id coming correct but it showing    syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting => ....update({:id => user_id},{$set: {verification_code:"null"}})

Comment: Try it with using multi:true